# Append to a json array multiple times in Python

Tags: python, json

I want to write a code in python to create a sample JSON file in a by duplicating the objects 'array' object x number of times to create a large file with the required format using an existing smaller JSON file.

smaller JSON sample file:

```
{"item":"book1","price":"10.00","array"[{"object1":"var1","object2":"var2"}]}
```

output file:

```
{"item":"book1","price":"10.00","array"[{"object1":"var1","object2":"var2"},{"object1":"var1","object2":"var2"},{"object1":"var1","object2":"var2"},......]}
```

I have tried this but I can figure out how to just duplicate the objects in the array:

```
result = ''
x = 2
with open("test.json", "r") as infile:
    for i in range(x):
        infile.seek(0)
        result += infile.read() + ','

with open("merged.json", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(result)
```

which gives me this:

```
{"item":"book1","price":"10.00","array"[{"object1":"var1","object2":"var2"}]},{"item":"book1","price":"10.00","array"[{"object1":"var1","object2":"var2"}]}
```

Comment: ok so what have you tried?

Comment: @SuperStew updated with what i have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use json and do something like this.

```
import json
myfile='test.json'

with open(myfile) as jfile:
    data=json.loads(jfile.read())

x=5 #x can be how many duplicates you want to make
data['array']=data['array']*x

with open(myfile,'w') as jfile:
    json.dumps(data,jfile)
```